# How should I decode this json response?

Tags: android, json, api, dart, flutter

I want to decode a server response in my flutter app,so this is the json response I get from server:

```
"{'UserId':'1','UserName':'sorena','Name':'behzad'}"
```

and this is the flutter code:

```
class HomeState extends State<Home>{
  Map user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
  }

  getUser() async {
    var response = await http.get('http://samplename.com/user/1');
    user = json.decode(response.body);
    print(user['UserId']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child : Text('hi')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

when I want to just print the UserId inside getUser(),I get this error:
(Basically I should be able to do that, right? cause I used it by another json responses and there was no problem)

```
E/flutter (28417): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>
```

I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to validate the json response and when I enter the json response in the question,it passes RFC 7159 standard test but RFC 4627 test fails.

and again I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com for json response examples in https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and both tests are passed and the json response works as expected in my app. does it give you any clue?

so why can't I decode this response? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code works fine. Error must be something else. Can I see your full code.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the json response, dont you think so?

Comment: I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to validate the json response and when I enter the json response in the question,it passes RFC 7159 standard test but RFC 4627 test fails.

Comment: and again I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com  for json response examples in https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and both tests are passed and the json response works as expected in my app. does it give you any clue?

Comment: What is your exact response from server?

Comment: Your json as posted above is incorrect. The tag names (e.g. `UserName`) must be double quotes (`"UserName"`) not single quotes (`'UserName'`). Please update the question with the actual JSON.

Comment: @RichardHeap It is the actual response i get! ,

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow:

```
var user = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(user['userId']);
```

A more complete solution would be to use [json serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable)

Comment: it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

did you try import dart:convert and use jsonDecode()

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Also the json keys format spec requires double quotes.

```dart
  String body='{"UserId":"1","UserName":"sorena","Name":"behzad"}';
  var user=(json.decode(body));
  print(user['UserId']);
```

the values do not need to be double quoted so you could leave them alone if they are not in a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the json  map type

```
Map<String,dynamic> result = Map<String,dynamic>.from(json.decode(body.data));

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys,
I ended up telling backend people to change the response(removing leading and trailing double quotations and using double quotations for Strings).